# Open a lightning Component when save a record?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have a custom lightning community and need to open a custom lightning component when a user press save on standard event page layout, it is possible to achieve this?

What would be the best way?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From standard save button we can't call any custom component. In fact we can not override  standard save button.

You can try creating custom lightning button component and put that on layout page. In that case you have to take care of save functionality as well.

Comment: But how can i hide the standart save button? It is neccesary to create and entire component for event creation right?

Comment: Actually you can't hide save button. You have to go with custom component.